# connection problems,net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: go

I was practicing with my application made with go and vue, but suddenly the server started to generate an error which says net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, what I first did was restart the pc, but the problem perceived, so I tried to connect directly through 127.0.0.1, but the problem continues, so what I did was change the port where the application was initializing but the problem did not stop, for a moment I thought that the application had broken it, so I created a test one to verify the connection with localhost, but also in the new application continued with the error.
This is a simple Go sample code:

```
func Handler() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

    r.Use(middleware.RequestID)
    r.Use(middleware.RealIP)
    r.Use(middleware.Logger)
    r.Use(middleware.Recoverer)

    r.Route("/api/v1/users", func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Post("/login", Login)
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9000", r))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any error messages from Go backend side?

Comment: no, go does not generate an error

Comment: Are you using docker or how exactly are you starting your server?

Comment: It is not Docker, i just run the app created directly

Comment: I think error is in your `app.js` file

Comment: but no matter what client application you use, it keeps giving the same error